# how do I get xstream to combine mouse events?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cyclejs, xstream-js

I'm experimenting with drag-and-drop using cyclejs in a codepen. The standard drag methods supported by HTML 5 don't seem to support constraints on the movement of the dragged object so I went with standard mousedown/mousemove/mouseup. It works, but not consistently. The combine() operation doesn't seem to trigger even when the debug() calls show that mousedown and mousemove events have been received and sometimes the mouseup is missed. Perhaps my understanding of the operation is incomplete or incorrect. A direct link to the codepen is provided at the bottom of this post. Any help appreciated!

```
const xs = xstream.default;
const { run } = Cycle;
const { div, svg, makeDOMDriver } = CycleDOM;

function DragBox(sources) {
  const COMPONENT_NAME = `DragBox`;

  const intent = function({ DOM }) {
    return {
      mousedown$: DOM.select(`#${COMPONENT_NAME}`)
        .events("mousedown")
        .map(function(ev) {
          return ev;
        })
        .debug("mousedown"),
      mousemove$: DOM.select(`#${COMPONENT_NAME}`)
        .events("mousemove")
        .map(function(ev) {
          return ev;
        })
        .debug("mousemove"),
      mouseup$: DOM.select("#container")
        .events("mouseup")
        .map(function(ev) {
          return ev;
        })
        .debug("mouseup")
    };
  };

  const between = (first, second) => {
    return source => first.mapTo(source.endWhen(second)).flatten();
  };

  const model = function({ mousedown$, mousemove$, mouseup$ }) {
    return xs
      .combine(mousedown$, mousemove$)
      .debug("combine")
      .map(([mousedown, mousemove]) => ({
        x: mousemove.pageX - mousedown.layerX,
        y: mousemove.pageY - mousedown.layerY
      }))
      .compose(between(mousedown$, mouseup$))
      .startWith({
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      })
      .debug("model");
  };

  const getStyle = left => top => {
    return {
      style: {
        position: "absolute",
        left: left + "px",
        top: top + "px",
        backgroundColor: "#333",
        cursor: "move"
      }
    };
  };

  const view = function(state$) {
    return state$.map(value =>
      div("#container", { style: { height: "100vh" } }, [
        div(`#${COMPONENT_NAME}`, getStyle(value.x)(value.y), "Move Me!")
      ])
    );
  };

  const actions = intent(sources);
  const state$ = model(actions);
  const vTree$ = view(state$);

  return {
    DOM: vTree$
  };
}

function main(sources) {
  const dragBox = DragBox(sources);

  const sinks = {
    DOM: dragBox.DOM
  };

  return sinks;
}

Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver("#app")
});
```

https://codepen.io/velociflapter/pen/bvqMGp?editors=1111

Comment: a debug() placed on the mapTo() stream produces output, but flatten() only produces output sporadically. When it does, the element is dragged. https://codepen.io/velociflapter/pen/YaRqYM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Testing your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/846k0rl03l) shows that `combine` is not getting the first `mousedown` event, apparently due to the `between` operator subscribing to `mousedown$` after the first mousedown event. Adding `remember` to the `mousedown$` sends that first mousedown event to the between operator subscription.

```
mousedown$: DOM.select(`#${COMPONENT_NAME}`)
  .events("mousedown").remember()
```

[Codepen.io `remember` example.](https://codepen.io/bloodyKnuckles/pen/LdMMPE?editors=0010)

[Codesandbox.io testing `between`](https://codesandbox.io/s/846k0rl03l)

---

Here's another CycleJS/xstream Drag and Drop approach (taking inspiration from this [RxJS Drag and Drop example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/dragndrop/dragndrop.js)) I think is more straight forward. Everything else in your code is essentially the same but the `model` function is this:

```
const model = function({ mousedown$, mousemove$, mouseup$ }) {
  return mousedown$.map(md => {
    let startX = md.offsetX, startY = md.offsetY
    return mousemove$.map(mm => {
      mm.preventDefault()
      return {
        x: mm.clientX - startX,
        y: mm.clientY - startY
      }
    }).endWhen(mouseup$)
  }).flatten().startWith({x:0,y:0})
};
```

Here's a [Codepen.io example](https://codepen.io/bloodyKnuckles/pen/jzQzep?editors=0010).

Comment: thanks knuckles.. yes - I'm not sure if you saw my later comment but I also suspect a problem due to between(). It puzzling because, at least on my system, sometimes it works. I've looked at the xstream code but it's written for speed/compactness so I may not be able to understand it well enough to get a fix in this time. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @JamesFremen A nights sleep helped me realize adding `remember` to the `mousedown$` preserves that initial mousedown event for the `between` operator.

Comment: I can reproduce your fix in my environment, too. That's good to know going forward - thanks again! Rather subtle if you're unused to a stream approach. It does seem reasonable in retrospect, though - the previous operators are consuming events.